# Upload video to Youtube without user autentication

Tags: ios, ipad, youtube, youtube-api

I'm building an iPad app (which is actually going to be part of a promotional kiosk), which lets whoever wants, to record a video (at the place, using the iPad), in order to get a chance to win a prize.

But I just realized that the Youtube API seems to have changed and now it requires user authentication in order to upload the video - which can't be done in my case.

Has anyone faced this problem before? Has anyone found an alternative to uploading the video from the iOS app directly to a specific Youtube account (which I've got full control of) without requiring user's authentication?

Help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For privacy issues, users have to upload videos into their accounts first. There is one way to get around it.

You can use [YouTube Direct Lite](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/).

So user's would still upload their videos with their own credentials, but then you have the option to moderate and approve those videos to have them in your playlist.

Otherwise if you try to login with only one account and upload all videos there, you will hit limits really soon.